# Why do i get the warning element is not allowed here? HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to make my first web page from memory after completing FCC HTML basics.  Why do i keep getting warnings, saying (p element is not allowed here, same for b, head, and most other tags.  I'm doing it exactly as ive been shown.  This still displays, but the yellow on my Pycharm has me uneasy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my website</title>
    </head>

    <main>
        <b>

        <h1>This is my Header</h1>

        <h2>This is where I describe my website</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut eros aliquet, convallis nulla vel, imperdiet mi. Fusce eu tellus nunc. Praesent consectetur in tortor nec eleifend. Nulla nisl neque, pretium sit amet faucibus sollicitudin, tincidunt et enim. Curabitur ipsum nisi, malesuada nec nisi eget, hendrerit ullamcorper ante. Sed pulvinar efficitur porttitor. Aliquam eleifend dapibus ipsum, dictum vestibulum lorem pellentesque eget. Aliquam efficitur nisl id sapien pulvinar interdum. Etiam molestie vulputate sapien a porttitor.

Nullam suscipit pellentesque augue. Nulla facilisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur neque arcu, dignissim non massa in, pellentesque vehicula massa. Quisque imperdiet odio ligula, eu ornare diam blandit eu. Maecenas ac massa eu mi tempor mattis. Donec imperdiet eros justo, eu semper ex commodo sit amet. Quisque finibus velit vitae nibh consequat vulputate. Mauris venenatis egestas mauris sit amet viverra. Vestibulum venenatis iaculis lectus in placerat. Integer in ipsum nibh. Fusce vitae euismod dolor, a mollis lorem.

Maecenas feugiat accumsan ipsum, non lobortis arcu imperdiet id. Fusce pharetra dui et ultrices imperdiet. Nam sed ex ipsum. Cras at tellus lobortis, molestie leo et, pharetra neque. Nullam pharetra urna quis porta ullamcorper. Nam tempus nisl a arcu suscipit dignissim. Sed condimentum, orci ac dignissim pellentesque, nisi ante pulvinar nulla, non posuere elit ligula et erat. Maecenas eget est et arcu efficitur lacinia. Sed et nunc vel diam tincidunt laoreet. Sed ut lorem ac nulla ultrices porttitor ut vel est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque eu enim fringilla, vestibulum lectus vel, vestibulum erat. Vestibulum quis efficitur massa. Morbi ac turpis vestibulum, consectetur quam gravida, tincidunt leo. Vivamus molestie neque nec nibh ullamcorper aliquet. Pellentesque at nunc felis.</p>










    </b>
    </main>
```

Comment: The <b> element is an inline element. If you want the text on the page to be bold, use a body{font-weight:bold} declaration in CSS.

Comment: You are also missing the <meta charset="utf-8"/> tag.  Also, where is your <body> tag?  The <main> tag is basically a div, it is not a substitute for <body>.

Comment: First time trying to go from memory, messed up the syntax.  Thought body was <b></b>

Answer (score 0):

`<main></main>` is not a supported HTML tag. It should be `<body></body>`.

**update**

You are about the “main” tag. However, I do see what may be your issue. It does not appear that your closes the “html” tag and you still need to add the “body” tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my website</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <main>
        <b>

        <h1>This is my Header</h1>

        <h2>This is where I describe my website</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut eros aliquet, convallis nulla vel, imperdiet mi. Fusce eu tellus nunc. Praesent consectetur in tortor nec eleifend. Nulla nisl neque, pretium sit amet faucibus sollicitudin, tincidunt et enim. Curabitur ipsum nisi, malesuada nec nisi eget, hendrerit ullamcorper ante. Sed pulvinar efficitur porttitor. Aliquam eleifend dapibus ipsum, dictum vestibulum lorem pellentesque eget. Aliquam efficitur nisl id sapien pulvinar interdum. Etiam molestie vulputate sapien a porttitor.

Nullam suscipit pellentesque augue. Nulla facilisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur neque arcu, dignissim non massa in, pellentesque vehicula massa. Quisque imperdiet odio ligula, eu ornare diam blandit eu. Maecenas ac massa eu mi tempor mattis. Donec imperdiet eros justo, eu semper ex commodo sit amet. Quisque finibus velit vitae nibh consequat vulputate. Mauris venenatis egestas mauris sit amet viverra. Vestibulum venenatis iaculis lectus in placerat. Integer in ipsum nibh. Fusce vitae euismod dolor, a mollis lorem.

Maecenas feugiat accumsan ipsum, non lobortis arcu imperdiet id. Fusce pharetra dui et ultrices imperdiet. Nam sed ex ipsum. Cras at tellus lobortis, molestie leo et, pharetra neque. Nullam pharetra urna quis porta ullamcorper. Nam tempus nisl a arcu suscipit dignissim. Sed condimentum, orci ac dignissim pellentesque, nisi ante pulvinar nulla, non posuere elit ligula et erat. Maecenas eget est et arcu efficitur lacinia. Sed et nunc vel diam tincidunt laoreet. Sed ut lorem ac nulla ultrices porttitor ut vel est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque eu enim fringilla, vestibulum lectus vel, vestibulum erat. Vestibulum quis efficitur massa. Morbi ac turpis vestibulum, consectetur quam gravida, tincidunt leo. Vivamus molestie neque nec nibh ullamcorper aliquet. Pellentesque at nunc felis.</p>
    </b>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this?  It's been explained to me this way in every tutorial.

Comment: <main> is, in fact a supported HTML5 tag. It behaves like a div, and it is a semantic tag similar to <aside>, <header>, and <nav>.

Comment: Yeah, I know that was my bad @ncmathsadist